# Get each line from a richtextbox and export to excel cells using c#

Tags: c#, loops, excel-interop

I am trying to loop through each line of the contents in the richtextBox and pass it to cells in each row in the same column. I cannot figure out how to get these two loops work together. Below is what I came up with:

```
                int length = richTextBox1.Lines.Length;
                for (int index = 1; index < length; index++)
                {
                    string content = string.Empty;
                    foreach (string str in richTextBox1.Lines)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[rowCount + index, 1] = str;
                    }
                 }
```

This loops through all the lines but I have not been able to extract each line to a different cell. This ends up giving me the last line of the richtextbox in each cell of the sheet. Any ideas is appreciated!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` to access each `string` object in the `Lines` property.

```
int length = richTextBox1.Lines.Length;

for (int index = 1; index < length; index++)
{
     workSheet.Cells[rowCount + index, 1] = richTextBox1.Lines[index];
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for reference.